# How do I share access to an AtomicBool between threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have this little program - essentially I want one thread to be able to tell the other to stop via a shared boolean in a struct.

```
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

struct Test {
    should_stop: AtomicBool,
    running_thread_handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>>
}

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test { 
            should_stop: AtomicBool::new(false), 
            running_thread_handles: Vec::new() 
        }
    }

    fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.should_stop.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }

    fn start(&mut self) {
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                println!("Looping");
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));

                // I want to effectively do this...
                /*
                if self.stop_bool.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                    println!("Stopping");
                    break;
                }*/
            }
        });

        self.running_thread_handles.push(handle);
    }
}

impl Drop for Test {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.stop();

        // Here I want to iterate the self.running_thread_handles and
        // make sure they are cleaned up
    }
}

// I expect to see a 4 "Looping" messages and then a "Stopping" message
fn main() {
   let mut test = Test::new();
   test.start();
   thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000));
   test.stop();
}
```

Perhaps there is a better approach altogether but I figure this is probably a good way to understand the lifetime stuff a bit.

I thought that all I need is an `Arc` so I tried this:

```
fn start(&mut self) {
    let stop_bool = Arc::new(&self.should_stop).clone();

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            println!("Looping");
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));

            if stop_bool.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                println!("Stopping");
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    self.running_thread_handles.push(handle);
}
```

That gives me this error:

> error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements

I figure the compiler does not understand the lifetime of the threads since all I am doing is storing the handles in a vector so I need to tell it somehow, but how?

If I declare the struct like this would I be getting nearer to making it work?

```
struct Test<'a> {
    should_stop: AtomicBool,
    running_thread_handles: &'a Vec<JoinHandle<()>>
}
```

I also have secondary, related, troubles that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to iterate through my vector of handles and call any functions on them in the `Drop` impl.  I suppose that the solution to that would be related, so I will not ask that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two ways to access variables between threads:

- borrowing, which requires guaranteeing that the variable's lifetime exceeds the threads' lifetime
- shared ownership (via `Arc`):

Borrowing is not supported by the Standard Library at the moment, although 3rd-party crates such as [crossbeam](https://github.com/aturon/crossbeam) offer it. For shared ownership, `Arc` is indeed a possibility...

... however you need to consider what you put in `Arc` carefully:

```
let stop_bool = Arc::new(&self.should_stop).clone();
```

Here, you are creating a `Arc<&'a AtomicBool>` from a `&'a self`, and thus you are sharing ownership over a *borrowed* reference. I'll point you back to the above explanation: cross-thread borrowing is not supported in the Standard Library yet.

You need a `Arc<AtomicBool>` for proper shared ownership, and this is done by changing `Test`:

```
struct Test {
    should_stop: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    running_thread_handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>>
}
```

Then, cloning it is easy:

```
let stop_bool = self.should_stop.clone();
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  I was about to run into a deep tunnel I think when instead the solution was pretty straight forward.

Comment: Has this changed in the years since? Not being able to share an AtomicBool easily across threads is... well, terrible. It's kind-of the point, so having to wrap it in other types like Arc is not a great experience.

Comment: @LeviMorrison: There is a work in progress for scoped threads to make their way back in the standard library, see [the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93203). Apart from that, do remember that Rust is about _control_, and notably control of the memory layout. There are many ways in which an atomic boolean can be needed: you may want a global, a single boolean, a boolean with some other state, etc... hence the standard library providing the brick (the atomic boolean) and letting customize how to lay it out in memory as suits your particular situation.

Comment: I'm new to Rust and came across this questions trying to achieve the same thing. Is there a way to encapsulate the two variables ('should_stop' and 'stop_bool') in the same struct? In other words I want to have a single 'struct StopFlag' which has 'is_stoped()' and 'set()' methods. Each method operate on a different member of the struct and, somehow, only the cloned stop_bool member gets moved to the closure while the should_stop member does not.

Comment: @smichak: Your comment is very unclear, I am afraid. I would advise you to ask a question instead, where you can display the code you attempted to write, and which fails, as it'll make it much clearer than attempting to describe the code in plain English.

Answer (score 18):

I'm posting my own answer here to hopefully provide a clear generic example, since the accepted answer is quite specific to the original question and left me slightly unsure how to do it:

```
use std::{thread, time};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
  let stop = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)); 
  let stop_me = stop.clone();
  thread::spawn(move || {
      let mut i = 0;
      loop {
          i = i + 1;
          if stop_me.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
              println!("iterations = {}", i);
              break;
          }
          if i % 1000000 == 0 {
              println!("Another million iterations down...");
          }
      }
  });
  let delay = time::Duration::from_millis(100);
  thread::sleep(delay);
  stop.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
  println!("All done");
}
```

Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a36363b361b5b933d9e70989a18d67a