# How to create a thread manager?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a data stream that I want to process in the background, but I want to create a struct or some functions to manage this stream.

In C++ land, I would create a class that abstracts all of this away. It would have a `start` method which would initialize the data stream and start a thread for processing. It would have a `stop` method that stops the processing and joins the thread.

However, this isn't really Rusty, and it doesn't even work in Rust.

Example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88c6f0cf2b5ea4748c95a897bcbed7de))

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct Handler {
    worker_handle: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    stop_flag: bool, // Should be atomic, but lazy for example
}

impl Handler {

    pub fn new() -> Handler {
        let worker_handle = None;
        let stop_flag = true;

        return Handler { worker_handle, stop_flag };
    }

    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        self.stop_flag = false;
        self.worker_handle = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("Spawned");
            self.worker_fn();
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        let handle = match self.worker_handle {
            None => return,
            Some(x) => x,
        };
        self.stop_flag = true;
        handle.join();
    }

    fn worker_fn(&mut self) {
        while !self.stop_flag {
            println!("Working!");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut handler = Handler::new();
    handler.start();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10000));
    handler.stop();
}
```

Output:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:54
   |
20 |           self.worker_handle = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
   |  ______________________________________________________^
21 | |             println!("Spawned");
22 | |             self.worker_fn();
23 | |         }));
   | |_________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 18:5...
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
18 | /     pub fn start(&mut self) {
19 | |         self.stop_flag = false;
20 | |         self.worker_handle = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
21 | |             println!("Spawned");
22 | |             self.worker_fn();
23 | |         }));
24 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &mut Handler
              found &mut Handler
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:20:54: 23:10 self:&mut Handler]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:20:35
   |
20 |         self.worker_handle = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Even if I cheat and remove the call the `worker_fn`, I still can't really work with `JoinHandle`s like I might expect from C++ land.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.worker_handle.0` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/main.rs:27:28
   |
27 |         let handle = match self.worker_handle {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.worker_handle`
28 |             None => return,
29 |             Some(x) => x,
   |                  -
   |                  |
   |                  data moved here
   |                  move occurs because `x` has type `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

So it's clear that I'm going outside of the usual Rust model and probably shouldn't be using this strategy.

But I still want to build *some* kind of interface that lets me simply spin up the data stream without worrying about managing threads, and I'm not really sure the best way to do this.

So it seems I have two core problems.

1) How can I create a function to be run in a thread which accepts data from an outside source, and can be signaled to quit safely? If I had an atomic bool for killing it, how would I share that between the threads?

2) How do I handle joining the thread when I'm done? The `stop` method needs to clean up the thread, but I don't know how to track a reference to it.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I share access to an AtomicBool between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33911792/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Joining a thread in a method that takes `&mut self` (like drop) results in “cannot move out of borrowed content”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41331577/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for those links, they have resolved my issues! I did search a lot before posting, but I didn't know enough about what should be done to resolve my issue to figure out what to search, especially for the second issue. Thank you very much for your reply. I have no real preference between deleting the question or marking as duplicate, since it is a duplicate of two questions wrapped into one over-arching question.